# recordId is blank in imperative call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, imperativeapex

I have an lwc action button that loads the popup. When i load the component for first time, recordId is present. But when i close and open it again(without reloading the whole page), recordId is lost. Kindly advise

```
export default class EmeaSubmitEvalRequest extends LightningElement {
_recordId;

@api set recordId(value) {
    this._recordId = value;
    console.log('in setter',this._recordId);
}

get recordId() {
    return this._recordId;
}
constructor(){
    super();
    console.log('constrcu',this.recordId);//not printed at all
}
connectedCallback(){
    console.log('connected recid',this.recordId);//not printed at all
}
@wire(invokeMuleService) 
getDropdownOptions({error,data}){
   if(data){
    this.defaultValues();
   }
}


   @wire(fetchExistingValues,{'evalId':'$recordId'}) preLoadValues({error,data}){
//do some logic here
}
```

Comment: Check this Thread might help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344045/recordid-is-undefined-in-lwc-quick-action-component

Comment: @AmanPatil Thanks but this still doesnt work :(

Comment: could you try implementing `rednderedCallback(){console.log(this.recordId)}`

Comment: also you could check this https://www.salesforceben.com/create-lightning-web-components-lwc-using-quick-actions/

Comment: @AmanPatil Thanks for your inputs the first comment you provided worked after some adjustments but now it looks like it doesnt invoke the fetchexisting values method OR it might be showing stale data. I have UPDATED the code

Comment: Its ok. I resolved it using refreshApex method and it worked to refresh stale data

Answer (score -2):

Just create @api variable like this:

@api recordId;

and use this in wire method like:

@wire(fetchExistingValues, { evalId: "$recordId" })

preLoadValues({error,data}){

```
//do some logic here
```

}

handleClick() {

fetchExistingValues({recId: this.recordId})

.then(function(res){ })

}

Comment: If you read the comments, you would have noticed that the OP solved it, but (unfortunately) didn't create an answer. Why should the original question be solved by using a simple variable instead of set/get? This reduces, not enhances reactivity. Or what have I overlooked?!